# Get MenuItem Name by Click Event

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, nullreferenceexception, menuitem

I want to get the `MenuItem` Name by clicking on it.

As far as I got there is my `Menu` with two `MenuItem`s in it (as you can see).

**XAML:**

```
<DockPanel Margin="0,-17,0,0">
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_Optionen">
            <MenuItem Name="MI_1" Header="MI 1" Click="Set_MI"/>
            <MenuItem Name="MI_2" Header="MI 2" Click="Set_MI"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <StackPanel></StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

**C#:**

```
private void Set_MI(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var MI = sender as MenuItem;
    switch (MI.Name)
```

I tried to convert the `object sender` in a `MenuItem` which throws me this Error:

> The error Shows up at Switch (MI.Name)
>
> System.NullReferenceException: "The object reference was not set to an object instance."
>
> "MI" is "null"

*Btw. I have no clue what `ToolStripMenuItem` is / means.*

Is there any propper solution to convert the `object sender` in a `MenuItem` / get the Name by clicking on the `MenuItem`?

Comment: What you mean _"dont work"_? It throwing exception, giving some error, not expected value?

Comment: There is [MenuItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem(v=vs.110).aspx), for WPF, and there is [ToolStripMenuItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem(v=vs.110).aspx), for WinForms. You have a tag for WPF but in code use `ToolStripMenuItem`. Please clarify that first. Also, "dont work for me" is too vague, are you getting an error?

Comment: If my suspicion is true and its a simple case of wrong cast, simply try `var MI = sender as MenuItem; switch (MI.Name)`

Comment: Where do you set a Name for an item? There are 3 possibilities - Name, Tag, Text. Look at this properties, maybe you find there your name

Comment: @KeyurPATEL it throws the same exception: System.nullreferenceexeption

Comment: It is because your sender is MenuItem, not ToolStripMenuItem

Comment: @Sasha I'm not sure if OP tried my suggestion and still got the null reference exception.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL probably not, that's why I wrote one more time

Comment: This is a great mystery, since the code and xaml looks fine (I even tried on a blank project myself). If possible, @Hille could you put a breakpoint in the code and see what `sender` actually looks like?

Comment: @KeyurPATEL i tried both (ToolStripMenuItem & MenuItem) it throws everytime the Null Reference Exception

Comment: Is sender null in debug mode?

Comment: @Sasha no its filled with the MenuItem (Name="MI_1")

Comment: The error Shows up at Switch (MI.Name)

Comment: You could try with `var MI = sender as Button`, it probably won't work, but doesn't hurt to try. Also try `EventArgs` instead of `RoutedEventArgs`. Again, probably won't make a difference, but why not.

Comment: @Hille try mi.name.tostring()

Comment: You can put a breakpoint in the event handler and you can check what type  `sender` argument is from Immediate Window by typing `sender.GetType().Name`.

Comment: i must agree my failture, no one of your tipps fixed the Problem, i give up and do a hardcoded style of Switch :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you cast to a `System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem` and not some other kind of custom `MenuItem` type:

```
private void Set_Speicherpfade(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var MI = sender as System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem;
    if (MI != null)
    {
        switch (MI.Name)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work, ist sais evertime MI = null. And i dont now the Kind of the MenuItem, i created it in wpf so i think ist a Windows controls.

Comment: The code I posted does work if the event handler is actually attached to a MenuItem. If you debug your code by putting a breakpoint in the event handler, what type is sender? Did you actually try my code?

Comment: I must admit, i put it at the worng spot at my Combobox but now it works fine .-. sry, but thanks for your effort

Comment: Can you please delete this answer so i can delete my question? I cant write any more questions becouse of my negative votes by one users ...